# Joomla 3.x Multilanguages RewriteRule

Tags: apache2, url-rewriting, joomla3.0

I have an issue. I set up my joomla 3.3.x with multilanguages.

URL how it appears in the browser:

`www.example.com/%LANG%/folder1/module1/images/img.png`

`%LANG%` stands for `de`, `en`, ...

And now the actually path where my image is(this is just an example, images/files could be anywhere):

`www.example.com/folder1/module1/images/img.png`

I thought about a rewrite rule which should get this work.

Comment: If it is a `custom_html` **module** you have to use absolute paths. If not, you have make the appropriate addition in the module code.